# Parsing YAML Front matter in Java

Tags: java, parsing, yaml, jekyll, snakeyaml

I have to parse [`YAML Front Matter`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) in `java` like `jekyll`, So Iooked into the source code, and [found this](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/features/step_definitions/jekyll_steps.rb#L16) but I can't make much sense of it(I don't know much ruby).

So My Question is, How do I parse `YAML Front Matter` in java ?

I have [snakeyaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) in my classpath and I would be parsing `YAML Front Matter` from a markdown file, for which I use [pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown)

Comment: There are several YAML libraries available for java, snakeyaml is one of them. So what exactly is your problem with reading YAML from the front matter?

Comment: My question is how do I separate YAML front matter from markdown and parse it safely ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void parse(Reader r) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

    // detect YAML front matter
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line.isEmpty()) line = br.readLine();
    if (!line.matches("[-]{3,}")) { // use at least three dashes
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No YAML Front Matter");
    }
    final String delimiter = line;

    // scan YAML front matter
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    line = br.readLine();
    while (!line.equals(delimiter)) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    // parse data
    parseYamlFrontMatter(sb.toString());
    parseMarkdownOrWhatever(br);
}
```

To get a obtain `Reader`, you will probably need a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) or an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Comment: Come on @Arian, this is lower than a regex example, 


What about situations where the user uses more than 3 `-` or less than 3 `-` or what if the first line is just an empty line and then the yaml begins ,



All this is easy with regex , But I am looking for something more reliable than regex.

Comment: The format specification(1) clearly states that the first line contains exactly three dashes. (1)https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter

Comment: Sadly I can't apply that restriction

Comment: updated my answer. Depending on your input, you might want to replace the `equals(delimiter)` with another `matches`

Comment: @Gautam K: All situation in your first comment CAN NOT happen when it is YAML Front matter according to the spec. According to the spec, YAML front matter HAS TO BE at the beginning of the file, has to start with three dashes and has to end with it. everything else is optional.

Comment: So either you update your quetion not to be specific to YAML front matter, or you are simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since your comment clarified what your question is:

The yaml front matter is everything that is inside the lines with three dashes (`---`).
YAML Front matter is ALWAYS at the beginning od the file.

So you just have to parse the file and extract the YAML Front Matter from the start of the file. you can either parse it with an automaton or an RegEx. It's really up to you. It is always structured the same way:

```
---
some YAML here
---
Markdown / textile / HTML contents of file
```

Comment: I understand the regex method, But I am trying to avoid that if possible. So how do I do it with the `automaton`

Comment: It is like every parser you can possibly write. Read a line. if it is `---` switch a bool to true and start writing the YAMl to a buffer. if you hit `---``again switch the bool to false and stop writing to the buffer. Then your buffer contains all YAMl. Just make sure you only detect at the start of the file. It is really, really trivial, and giving code samples would mean posting a complete, working solution. And i don't think thats the purpose of SO.

Comment: I am not familiar with writing parser.

Comment: I have given you a complete instruction, you just need to write the actual code (which i will not, no matter how high you'll set a bounty). Maybe you can explain what your actual problem in writing the code is?

Comment: I have no issues with writing code , Its just that I have no clue as to where to begin writing a parser.

Comment: maybe you start with opening a file and reading the contents from the input stream?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in the front matter, you can use SnakeYaml's loadAll method:

```
Object yamlFrontMatter(Yaml yaml, InputStream in) {
    return yaml.loadAll().iterator().next();
}
```

SnakeYaml will only read the first yaml structure (the front matter) and ignore the trailing non-yaml text.

Unfortunately, SnakeYaml has no elegant way to output the remaining text, so if you want to parse both the front matter and the body at the same time, there is no advantage in this approach :-(